# select/deselect specific checkboxes in row

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

This question is in a context of a Kendo grid, but I believe it is equally applicable to a traditional table.

The grid has items down the left hand side and columns relating to the steps the items go through. Part of the functionality is that if a check box is checked, all the preceding check boxes in the row are set to be checked regardless of their initial state.

This is (due to the Kendo grid) assumed to be handled in a JQuery function, where the function checks whether the particular check box is checked or not, then applies the same checked status to all check boxes of the specific row that correspond to the classes that occur prior to the checked check box.

I'm lead to believe (from my currently limited knowledge in JQuery, and cutting/pasting various similar code snippets) that setting the previous check boxes requires something like the below code:

```
$("#Step2").change(function(){
    if ($('#Step2').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents('tr').closest(".Step1:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parents('tr').closest(".Step1:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

This however does not select the previous step's check box as desired.

The columns of the Kendo grid are as follows, if it helps:

```
columns: [
    { field: "Item" },
    { field: "Step1", title: "Step 1", attributes: {style: "text-align: center"}, template: '<input class="Step1" id="Step1" type="checkbox" #= Step1 ? "checked=checked" : "" # ></input>', headerTemplate: '<div style="text-align:center">Step 1<br/><input type="checkbox" id="step1Toggle"></input></div>' },
    { field: "Step2", title: "Step 2", attributes: {style: "text-align: center"}, template: '<input class="Step2" id="Step2" type="checkbox" #= Step2 ? "checked=checked" : "" # ></input>', headerTemplate: '<div style="text-align:center">Step 2<br/><input type="checkbox" id="step2Toggle"></input></div>' },
    { field: "Step3", title: "Step 3", attributes: {style: "text-align: center"}, template: '<input class="Step3" id="Step3" type="checkbox" #= Step3 ? "checked=checked" : "" # ></input>', headerTemplate: '<div style="text-align:center">Step 3<br/><input type="checkbox" id="step3Toggle"></input></div>' },
    { field: "Step4", title: "Step 4", attributes: {style: "text-align: center"}, template: '<input class="Step4" id="Step4" type="checkbox" #= Step4 ? "checked=checked" : "" # ></input>', headerTemplate: '<div style="text-align:center">Step 4<br/><input type="checkbox" id="step4Toggle"></input></div>' },
    { field: "Step5", title: "Step 5", attributes: {style: "text-align: center"}, template: '<input class="Step5" id="Step5" type="checkbox" #= Step5 ? "checked=checked" : "" # ></input>', headerTemplate: '<div style="text-align:center">Step 5<br/><input type="checkbox" id="step5Toggle"></input></div>' }
]
```

Comment: I assume the grid is bound to a model of some kind? And if so, do you need to edit the grid row to be able to check/uncheck a checkbox? Because if this is the case you could put some code in the edit event handler to set the 'step' properties of the model based on the current step and then when the changes are saved/committed all the required checkboxes would get checked automatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post and based on my earlier comment I think that the functionality you are looking to achieve can be seen in the below jFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/neilhibbert/kmc6z/10/

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br/>
```

Kendo UI/JS

```
var dataModel = [{ ColourId: 1, Colour: "Red", Step1: true, Step2: false, Step3: false, Step4: false, Step5: false},{ ColourId: 2, Colour: "Green", Step1: false, Step2: false, Step3: false, Step4: false, Step5: false},{ ColourId: 3, Colour: "Blue", Step1: false, Step2: false, Step3: false, Step4: false, Step5: false}];

$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport:{
            read: function(o) {
                o.success(dataModel);
            },
            create: function(o) {
                o.success(o.data);
            },
            update: function(o) {
                var dataItem = o.data, i, j;
                for(i = 5; i>0; i-=1) {
                    if(dataItem['Step' + i] === true) {
                        for(j = i-1; j>0; j-=1) {
                            dataItem['Step' + j] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                o.success(dataItem);
            },
            destroy: function(o){
                o.success(o.data);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(response) { return response || []; },
            model: {
                id: 'ColourId',
                fields: {
                    ColourId: { type: 'number' },
                    Colour: { type: 'string', editable: false },
                    Step1: { type: 'boolean' },
                    Step2: { type: 'boolean' },
                    Step3: { type: 'boolean' },
                    Step4: { type: 'boolean' },
                    Step5: { type: 'boolean' },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    editable: {
        mode: 'inline'
    },
    save: function(e) {
        this.dataSource.sync();
    },
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Colour',
            field: 'Colour'
        },
        {
            title: 'Step 1',
            field: 'Step1',
            template: '<input name="Step1" type="checkbox" disabled #=Step1 === true ? "checked" : ""# />'
        },
        {
            title: 'Step 2',
            field: 'Step2',
            template: '<input name="Step2" type="checkbox" disabled #=Step2 === true ? "checked" : ""# />'
        },
        {
            title: 'Step 3',
            field: 'Step3',
            template: '<input name="Step3" type="checkbox" disabled #=Step3 === true ? "checked" : ""# />'
        },
        {
            title: 'Step 4',
            field: 'Step4',
            template: '<input name="Step4" type="checkbox" disabled #=Step4 === true ? "checked" : ""# />'
        },
        {
            title: 'Step 5',
            field: 'Step5',
            template: '<input name="Step5" type="checkbox" disabled #=Step5 === true ? "checked" : ""# />'
        },
        {
            title: 'Actions',
            command: [ 'edit' ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I hope this helps. The example uses a local data source but the principal is the same, the only caveat being that this makes use of the grids edit/non-edit modes so I don't know how much of a deal-breaker that is...

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the issue requires the check boxes to update on check; I've managed to work on the problem and figured out that I had the method that changes the 'checked' state nested in the document.ready function loading the grid; moving it out made it work with the functionality I needed. Thank you for responding, as it will help with the data-side of things when this moves from prototype to actual interaction with a database.